# Cognito - does it support separation of "local" and "federated" users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

For my app I want to use Cognito with a user pool that supports two classes of users:

1. A set of local users which are added by an administrator. These users are allowed to reset their passwords etc but cannot login using any federated service even if their id did exist in the associated federated service.
2. A set of users that are associated with a federated service; these can only login via this federated service and cannot use Cognito etc to set/reset a password for the local account that will be created etc.

Can this be supported by Cognito? Would I have to add a custom lambda triggers to identify if someone who was supposed to be a federated user was trying to set/reset a local password etc?